# Append Query Trouble

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having trouble with the final piece of my append query.  I have the records generating just like I want with the exception of not triggering until the Expression `Event Date is <=Date()`.  It is giving me a unmatched error when I place the `<=Date()` in the criteria field of the query builder.  I tried it with `DateSerial` and a few other variations.  I'm sure it has to do with the expression being that and not a hard date.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO SchedulingLog ( 
  UserID
  , LogDate
  , EventDate
  , Category
  , CatDetail
  , [Value] 
)
SELECT Roster.UserID
 , Date() AS LogDate
 , DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month([WM DOH]),Day([WM DOH])) AS EventDate
 , SchedulingLog.Category
 , SchedulingLog.CatDetail
 , Max(tblAccrual!WeeksAccrual*Roster!Schedule) AS [Value]
FROM tblAccrual
 , [Schedule Type]
 , Category 
    INNER JOIN CatDetail 
      ON Category.CategoryID = CatDetail.CategoryID
 , SchedulingLog 
    INNER JOIN Roster 
      ON SchedulingLog.UserID = Roster.UserID
WHERE (((tblAccrual.Years)<=Round((Date()-[wm doh])/365,2)))
GROUP BY Roster.UserID
  , Date()
  , DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month([WM DOH]),Day([WM DOH]))
  , SchedulingLog.Category
  , SchedulingLog.CatDetail
HAVING (((SchedulingLog.Category) Like "Vac*") 
           AND ((SchedulingLog.CatDetail) Like "Ann*"));
```

Comment: Does the `SELECT` part work by itself ... meaning when not included in an `INSERT` query?

Comment: It returns that same error in both instances.

Comment: Thought so.  Simplify the problem to make it easier to solve.  The problem is not because it's an append query; the problem is the `SELECT` is broken.  So fix that first.

Comment: I understand.  Any insight as to using a criteria field on an expression?

Comment: In the places where you aren't directly using [WM DOH] in a function, wrap it with CDate().  For example in the WHERE clause, `WHERE (((tblAccrual.Years)<=Round((Date()-CDate([wm doh]))/365,2)))`  Does that solve it?

Comment: Is `[WM DOH]` a parameter or a field in one of the tables?  If a field, which table?

Comment: [WM DOH] is a field in table [Roster].

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is not explicitly converting the user input date with CDate.  I suspect it's fine in most of the query because the [MW DOH] parameter is provided directly to functions which will convert it to date.  However the WHERE clause would need an explicit conversion.

The following generates the error "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to the variables."

```
SELECT Date()-[userinput] AS something;
```

Whereas the following code does not

```
SELECT Date()-CDate([userinput]) AS something;
```